# Has Alloy ever been used to specify itself rigorously?

Tags: alloy, metamodel

I would like to know if somebody has ever fully specified the Alloy language in Alloy.

If such a metamodel exists, is it publicly available?

Comment: Do you mean something in the style of J.M. Spivey's *Understanding Z* (Cambridge: CUP, 1988), but for Alloy?  I agree, that would be of significant interest.

Comment: Yes and no. 
No because, through I didn't go through all the book, it seems to me that his main concern is to provide a denotational semantics to Z. 
Yes because I run into section 1.3 titled meta-circulartiy which basically mention that Z can "express itself". I am sure Alloy can as well and was curious if it has ever been done

Answer (score -3):

Do you mean you'd like a reference like http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api but then based on the Alloy XML tags instead of the `Ti.` Javascript namespace? That's something I'd very much like to see happening as well, but I cannot give an estimate of when we'd have that atm.

Comment: I think OP was referring to [Alloy](http://alloy.mit.edu/), the modeling tool from MIT, and not to [Alloy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Command-Line_Interface_Reference), the project management tool from Appcelerator for managing Titanium mobile application development projects.

Comment: Indeed, note that the latter is tagged alloy-titanium, the tag Alloy being reserved to the modelling language (and tool) from MIT.

Comment: maybe you should delete this answer?